# How to have a 3d plot of a complex polynomial?

Tags: plotting, complex, polynomials

I'm trying to have a 3d plot for a complex polynomial using the ContourPlot3D It shows me a plot which does not vary when the input values of different variables are varied. So, I guess it is just a dummy plot I'm getting. Kindly guide me as how to get a correct 3d plot. I'm using Mathematica version 9.

```
omegaJ = (0.41*10^-5)^-1; 
lambdaJ = 1.724*10^15; 
n0 = 10^12;
zion = 1.602*10^-19;
e = 1.602*10^-19;

t0 = 10^6;
melec = 9.1094*10^-31;
Subscript[ν, i] = 1.00*10^1;
Subscript[ν, id] = 5.00*10^-3;
Subscript[ν, ed] = 1.00*10^2;
rdust = 37.5*10^-6;

telec = 2.6*10^4;
tion = .26*10^4;
temp = telec;

mion = 2*10^-14;
mnd = 4.0*10^-16;

grav = 6.67*10^-11;
veff = 10;
nion = 2*10^5;
η = 0.01;
cs = Sqrt[telec/mion]*(4*π*n0*mion*grav)^-0.5;

Subscript[n, e0] = 5*10^3;
Subscript[n, i0] = 10^3;
Subscript[ϕ, g] = -2.51*temp/e;
Subscript[q, d0] = rdust*Subscript[ϕ, g];

Subscript[I, e0] = 
   Abs[-π*rdust^2*e*Sqrt[((8*telec)/(π*melec))]*Subscript[n, e0] * Exp[(e*Subscript[q, d0])/(rdust*telec)]];
Subscript[I, i0] = Abs[π*rdust^2*e*Sqrt[((8*tion)/(π*mion))]*Subscript[n, i0]*
Exp[1 - (e*Subscript[q, d0])/(rdust*tion)]];
Subscript[ν, ndch] = 10^4*e;

SuperStar[c] = (-Subscript[ν, ed] + Subscript[ν, i] - 2*n0*veff)/omegaJ;

SuperStar[d] = ((3*η*omegaJ)/(
              melec*n0*lambdaJ*ξ^2)) + ((η*omegaJ*k^2)/(
                melec*n0*lambdaJ));

SuperStar[q] = (4*π*e^2*n0*lambdaJ^2)/telec ; 
a4 = telec/(mion*cs^2);
r1 = zion*(2*veff*n0 - Subscript[ν, i]);
r2 = - telec*(1/(melec*lambdaJ) + (Subscript[q, d0]*omegaJ)/(e*mnd));

r4 = a4*zion*omegaJ;
r5 = a4*Subscript[I, i0]*omegaJ;

p1 = SuperStar[c]*SuperStar[d]*SuperStar[
q]*(e*r4*Subscript[ν, ndch] + r5) ; 

p3 = (e*r1*Subscript[ν, ndch] + 
Subscript[I, e0]*Subscript[ν, id] + r1*Subscript[I, i0]) * SuperStar[q]*r2 ; 
p4 = SuperStar[c]*SuperStar[d]*Subscript[ν, ndch]*Subscript[ν, id]*e;


q1 = (SuperStar[d]*Subscript[ν, ndch]*e*r4 - 
SuperStar[c]*cs*omegaJ*Subscript[ν, ndch]*e*r4 - 
omegaJ*SuperStar[c]*SuperStar[d]*e*r4 + SuperStar[d]*r5 - 
SuperStar[c]*cs*omegaJ*r5)*SuperStar[q] ; 

q3 = (e*r1 + Subscript[I, e0])*omegaJ*r2*SuperStar[q];
q4 = (SuperStar[d]*Subscript[ν, ndch]*Subscript[ν, id] - 
       SuperStar[c]*cs*omegaJ*Subscript[ν, ndch]*Subscript[ν, 
          id] - SuperStar[c]*SuperStar[d]*omegaJ*Subscript[ν, id] - 
            SuperStar[c]*SuperStar[d]*omegaJ*Subscript[ν, ndch])*e;


(* Roots *)

y = (p1 + (p4 - p3)*(1/ξ - I k))/(q1 + (q3 + q4)*(1/ξ - I k));
x == 0;


(* Plot *)
ContourPlot3D[y, {y, 0, 10}, {ξ, 0.01, 10}, {k, 1, 100}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"y", "ξ", "k"}, AxesLabel -> {"y", "ξ", "k"},
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, Mesh -> None, 
  ContourStyle -> Directive[Red, Opacity[0.8], Specularity[White, 30]]]

η = 0.03;

y - (p1 + (p4 - p3)*(1/ξ - I k))/(q1 + (q3 + q4)*(1/ξ - I k)) == 0;
ContourPlot3D[y, {y, 0, 10}, {ξ, 0.01, 10}, {k, 1, 100}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"y", "ξ", "k"}, AxesLabel -> {"y", "ξ", "k"},
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, Mesh -> None, 
  ContourStyle -> Directive[Red, Opacity[0.8], Specularity[White, 30]]]

η = 0.05;

y = (p1 + (p4 - p3)*(1/ξ - I k))/(q1 + (q3 + q4)*(1/ξ - I k));
ContourPlot3D[y, {y, 0, 10}, {ξ, 0.01, 10}, {k, 1, 100}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"y", "ξ", "k"}, AxesLabel -> {"y", "ξ", "k"},
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, Mesh -> None, 
  ContourStyle -> Directive[Red, Opacity[0.8], Specularity[White, 30]]]

mnd = 5.0*10^-16;

y = (p1 + (p4 - p3)*(1/ξ - I k))/(q1 + (q3 + q4)*(1/ξ - I k));
ContourPlot3D[y, {y, 0, 10}, {ξ, 0.01, 10}, {k, 1, 100}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"y", "ξ", "k"}, AxesLabel -> {"y", "ξ", "k"},
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, Mesh -> None, 
  ContourStyle -> Directive[Red, Opacity[0.8], Specularity[White, 30]]]
```

I want to have a 3d plot for the equation as below with the value of y,xi and k along the three axes.

I've done the changes as advised by the experts in the forum.

Kindly let me know if Contourplot3d can be used for plotting complex plots or not.

```
enter code here
```

> y = (p1 + (p4 - p3)*(1/ξ - I k))/(q1 + (q3 + q4)*(1/ξ - I k));

```
enter code here
```

Comment: You write `ContourPlot3D[y, {y, 0, 10}, {ξ, 0.01, 10}, {k, 1, 100}, ...]`, but $y$ has no value assigned to it, so you are pretty much plotting the equivalent of `Plot[y, {y, 0, 10}]`. What are you trying to do here? Your code looks weird in places. For instance, you have some equations set up right before the `ContourPlot`, but those are not assigned to anything so they do not do anything for your calculations. You need to explain what you are trying to do. Otherwise this is a very long code dump, and it would take a lot of time and patience for somebody to understand it enough to fix it.

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1994151).

Comment: Actually, y *does* have a value assigned to it, namely, the expression involving the `p`s and `q`s, so it does not make sense to me then to use `y` as one of the variables in any kind of plot. Moreover, `y` is complex-valued.

Comment: Sample some values of `Re[y]` and `Im[y]` to try to see what is happening. For example, the output from `Table[Re[y], {\[Xi], 0.1, 10, 0.5}, {k, 10, 100, 5}] // TableForm` seems to show that `Re[y]` is essentially constant! So does `Plot3D[Re[y], {\[Xi], 0.1, 10}, {k, 10, 100}]`. Look at `Plot3D[Im[y], {\[Xi], 0.1, 10}, {k, 10, 100}, PlotRange -> All]`.

Comment: The question asked was whether "Contourplot3d can be used for plotting complex plots or not." Try reading the documentation, please.

Comment: I've tried the commands Plot3D both for Re[y] and Im[y]. It gives a plot which does not scale and does not show any variation when input values are changed.

Comment: @RahulChakraborty: As I said, `Re[y]` seems to be essentially constant over the domain of values you specify for `k` and `\[xi]`. But `im[y]` does not: I see quite a "bumpy" output from `Plot3D[Im[y], {\[Xi], 0.1, 10}, {k, 10, 100}, PlotRange -> All]`. That is using what is posted in your original question here.